# What is the proper solution for logging on a StringBuffer object using log4j over SLF4J?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, appender

I want to know if there's something already done, an ext library to do such thing?
I need the logger to be redirected to a StringBuffer for then ALL that text to be included in a database record as a message.
First of all, is that a good practice??
What I'm doing now is using a new Appender class and having that StringBuffer object, then retrieving and storing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom logging to gather messages at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002926/custom-logging-to-gather-messages-at-runtime)

Comment: What do you mean "ALL that text"? Do you mean the StringBuffer stores up results of multiple logging calls and then periodically its contents get written to a database?

Comment: Yes Nathan, exactly that, althought not periodically but when the application's processing steps finish.

Comment: Just checked @dogbane, it's that, but that buffer must be shared by all classes within the application. I'm finding for a proper solution, avoiding to share a static field across it. What that link says is what I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

A custom log4j appender is the way to go in your case and it's transparent for SLF4J.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and wrote my own at some point https://github.com/artgo/stringbuffer-logger