# log4j:Appender to print the log Statements

Tags: java, log4j, fileappender

Hello sir:
             When server is started ,the log files print the output statement..how can i print the log files in my own file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure a log4j properties file with file appender. Something like this -

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, fileAppender
log4j.logger.myPackage=DEBUG, fileAppender
log4j.additivity.myPackage=false
log4j.appender.fileAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileAppender.File= C://Myfile.log
log4j.appender.fileAppender.MaxFileSize=1024KB 
log4j.appender.fileAppender.MaxBackupIndex=5 
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
```

Comment: Actually my Question is creating one own appender in that i
have to catch log details and send it through web service...how can i do
please guide me

Comment: Go thorugh these links, hope it helps. http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-initialize-log4j-in-a-web-application.html?page=1 http://blog.idleworx.com/2010/01/setting-up-log4j-for-simple-java-web.html

Answer (score 2):

You can try using a properties file

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, ERRORFILE

#ERRORFILE - used to log error messages
log4j.appender.ERRORFILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ERRORFILE.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.ERRORFILE.File=errorLog.log
log4j.appender.ERRORFILE.MaxFileSize=200KB
log4j.appender.ERRORFILE.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.ERRORFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ERRORFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{DATE} %t - %m%n
```

In this example, I configured a properties file to log error messages to my own file, `errorLog.log`. Here's another [sample](http://www.benmccann.com/blog/sample-log4j-properties-file/).