# log4j create file on demand

Tags: java, log4j

We have multiple batch jobs and using log4j for logging for each on of them. The issue is whenver a job is run empty log files are being created for all of the non-running jobs. Is there a way I can specify to create only log files for the currently running job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always create your own appender if you need some special functionality.  Take a look at this:  [How to create a own Appender in log4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072389/how-to-create-a-own-appender-in-log4j)

Also, when you say jobs, what exactly do you mean?  Do you have multiple processes running in their own JVMs?