# WSO2 Distributed logging

Tags: logging, wso2, wso2-bam

I am trying to send our application server logs to BAM. There is a documentation for how could we do it on the [wso2 web site](http://wso2.org/library/articles/20c12/11/distributed-logging-works-wso2-stratos).

However I could not understand how could we extend Log4JAppender. Is there any sample to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logging configuration can be found at http://sparkletechthoughts.blogspot.com/ for sending logs from app server to BAM. To view archived Logs from app server, Apache server used only from 4.0.0 to 4.0.3 carbon based products. After 4.0.3, hadoop need to be configured for this purpose.

You can use the already extended Log4jAppender as LogEventAppender which is available in CARBON-HOME/repository/log4j.properties of App server rather writing a new appender to send logs from app server to BAM.

In order to extend Log4jAppender for your own purpose, you can refer [How to create a own Appender in log4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072389/how-to-create-a-own-appender-in-log4j).