# How to display any type of error in java to the user while still logging it?

Tags: java, error-handling, log4j

I am trying to find a centralized way to display errors to the user while logging them. Want to display the whole error message as it is written to the log without any customization. We are using log4j to log the errors and want to do minimal changes to the code.

Comment: How do users interact with your program? Is it a swing application, a website, a command line utility etc

Comment: Its a website. The front end is developed using javascript and HTML5.

Comment: And what have you tried so far to present the error to the user?

Comment: Currently, we are handling it in each class while writing the error to the log.

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom `Appender` as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072389/how-to-create-a-own-appender-in-log4j). Add the `Appender` to your `Logger` and get notified about logging events and do with them whatever you want to.

Comment: Is there a way to do something from Controller?