# Log4J - Auto refresh log files, is it possible?

Tags: java, log4j, real-time

I've started to make tests, and all the output is sent to a ".log" file. In one test, I have to stop manually the application in a certain line of log.

The question is: Can a .log file work like a Console, displaying info in real time?

Comment: Add ConsoleAppender to your log4j configuration: http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can monitor a log file with `tail -f` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_%28Unix%29

Within your java code you can monitor its output see [java runtime.getruntime() getting output from executing a command line program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711084/java-runtime-getruntime-getting-output-from-executing-a-command-line-program)

or create your own appender [How to create a own Appender in log4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072389/how-to-create-a-own-appender-in-log4j)