# Dynamic monitoring of log file

Tags: java, logging

I need to monitor a log file for a pattern. The log file continually gets written by an application.

1. The application can add new log statements while my program is reading it.
2. The log gets rolled over when it’s >200 MB or at end of the day, so my program should handle change in filename dynamically.
3. If my program crashes for any reason, it has to resume from where it left off.

I do not want to re-invent the wheel. I am looking for a Java API. I wrote a program to read file and put in a loop with 30 seconds sleep, but that does not meet all the criteria.

Comment: >= Java 8: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might consider looking at apache commons io classes, in particular Tailer/TailerListener classes. See http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/commons-io-2.0/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.java.shtml.

Answer (score 2):

These two API's can be helpful:

### 1

[JxFileWatcher (Official Site)](http://java.dzone.com/announcements/new-java-library-monitor-file)

[Read here what it is capable of](http://java.dzone.com/announcements/new-java-library-monitor-file)

---

### 2

[Jnotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/)

JNotify is a java library that allow java application to listen to file system events, such as:

- File created
- File modified
- File renamed
- File deleted

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/index.html), or can integrate it, it is possible to append log outputs to a convenient object, such as a [StringBuffer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html), as it has been discussed in this related question: [Custom logging to gather messages at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1002926/851811)

Comment: I did look at socketAppender from log4j, intially it caused my log producer to slow down significantly. Next was to wrap log producer in AsyncAppender. That did free up Producer but then intermittently I would see 'EOF socket closed'. my testcase would generate 1mil events in 5mins window for perf test.

Answer (score 1):

This looks similar: [Implementation of Java Tail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557844/java-io-implementation-of-unix-linux-tail-f)

Essentially you use a BufferedReader. Tracking where you left off will be something you'll have to add, perhaps capture the last line read?

That same question references [JLogTailer](http://www.jibble.org/jlogtailer.php) which looks interesting and may do most of what you want already.